# MongoDB get size of unwinded array

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to return size of 'orders' and sum of 'item' values for each 'order' for each order from documents like the example document:

```
    orders: [
    {
        order_id: 1,
        items: [
            {
                item_id: 1,
                value:100
            },
            {
                item_id: 2,
                value:200
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        order_id: 2,
        items: [
            {
                item_id: 3,
                value:300
            },
            {
                item_id: 4,
                value:400
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm using following aggregation to return them, everything works fine except I can't get size of 'orders' array because after unwind, 'orders' array is turned into an object and I can't call $size on it since it is an object now.

```
db.users.aggregate([
{
    $unwind: "$orders"
},
{
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        total_values: {
            $reduce: {
                input: "$orders.items",
                initialValue: 0,
                in: { $add: ["$$value", "$$this.value"] }
            }
        },
        order_count: {$size: '$orders'}, //I get 'The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: object' error
    }
},
])
```

the result I expected is:

```
{order_count:2, total_values:1000} //For example document
{order_count:3, total_values:1500} 
{order_count:5, total_values:2500}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to get the results that I wanted. Here is the code

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1, orders: 1, order_count: { $size: '$orders' }
        }
    },
    { $unwind: '$orders' },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: '$_id', items: '$orders.items', order_count: '$order_count'
        }
    },
    { $unwind: '$items' },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: '$_id', sum: { $sum: '$items.value' }, order_count: '$order_count'
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { _id: '$_id', order_count: '$order_count' }, total_values: { $sum: '$sum' }
        }
    },
])
```

output:

```
{ _id: { _id: ObjectId("5dffc33002ef525620ef09f1"), order_count: 2 }, total_values: 1000 }
{ _id: { _id: ObjectId("5dffc33002ef525620ef09f2"), order_count: 3 }, total_values: 1500 }
```